# How to enumerate all members of an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In order to separate properties in an object into 2 groups (those that are declared in an interface which this object implements and all others) I need a way to get an array of property names from the interface. The first step is probably the `keyof` operator:

```
interface MyInterface {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

function f(i: MyInterface) {
    type props = keyof MyInterface;
}
```

Now I have an object passed into this function, for example:

```
f({ a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"} as MyInterface);
```

I see that `props` is `"a" | "b"`, while `i` contains `c` as additional property. If I could convert the `props` union type to string array then it would be trivial to extract the additional property, but don't see how I can do that.

Since converting the union type to a string array is only a means to find the additional properties I would also accept any other way to do that which is not based on the union type.

Comment: Types/interfaces do not exist at runtime..

Comment: True, but we can also use other type system stuff at runtime (typeof, instanceof etc.) even though all types are erased. My hope is that typescript generates a list of property names for me (or something along that line).

Comment: Nope.. You can only go the other way around: create an array of possible keys and generate the type from it (e.g. `const keys = ['a', 'b'] as const; type MyInterface  = {[K in typeof keys[number]]: string}`), but I guess it is not flexible enough

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-keys

Comment: `typeof` and `instanceof` operate on values, not on types. They are purely JavaScript constructs

Comment: @VitaliiIlchenko That seems to be the only solution. Please write an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "out of the box" way to do that. But there is an npm package which provides such feature: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-keys